# Making top navigation bar fixed when its position is set as relative

Tags: html, css

How do I make this top navigation bar fixed on top?

I understand that normally, you'd apply `position: fixed` to boxA, but that doesn't work in this case because its position has to be set as relative. The entire top navigation bar is to be sticky, so it stays on the page as people scroll down

```css
.boxA:after {
  content:"";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.boxA {
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0DCDC;
}

.boxA img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 3%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.box2 ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  right: 10px;
}


.box1 {
  float: left;
   width: auto;
}

.box2 {
  float: right;
  width: auto; 
}



.box2 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;  
}


.box2 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: 12px;
}

.box2 li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.box2 ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.box2 li {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Gotham';
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}


.box1 img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;

}
```

```html
<div class="boxA">


  <div class="box1">
    <div class="site">
      <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"></a>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <nav class="menu"> 
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#conD">menu1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#conG">menu2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#conH">menu3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#conI">menu4</a></li>    
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</div>
```

I tried adding `div class="top-nav"` right above `div class="boxA"`, and assign .top nav's position as fixed, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Add height to your body for better understanding. Add position fixed and top 0 and width 100% to your boxA class

```css
body {
  height: 900px;
}
.boxA:after {
  content:"";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.boxA {
  height: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0DCDC;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(12, 0, 46, .08);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(12, 0, 46, .08);
}

.body_part {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.boxA img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 3%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.box2 ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  right: 10px;
}


.box1 {
  float: left;
   width: auto;
}

.box2 {
  float: right;
  width: auto; 
}



.box2 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;  
}


.box2 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: 12px;
}

.box2 li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.box2 ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.box2 li {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Gotham';
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}


.box1 img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="boxA">


    <div class="box1">
      <div class="site">
        <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"></a>
      </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
      <nav class="menu"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#conD">menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#conG">menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#conH">menu3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#conI">menu4</a></li>    
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="body_part">
    <img src = "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked!  As I'm scrolling down, I'm noticing that while the top nav bar is correctly being fixed on top, it's sometimes placed BELOW certain elements - how do I fixed this?

Comment: check my edited answer, trying adding background and box-shadow, this may help you

Comment: Thanks. I did try it but the top nav bar still appears below certain elements! What could be causing this?

Comment: you have to create a class named body_part, and in body_part all the other things will be included

Comment: Hi thanks. I wrapped everything else in div=body_part, but I'm still having the problem.... what else could I try here? thanks so much

Comment: please try copy paste the css and HTML and let me know about this

Comment: Sorry the code is rather long, but here:  https://jsfiddle.net/benjaminana77/pugek2f8/  I'm having this error in 3 places (1) hero jquery animation - background should be white, but it looks transparent  https://imgur.com/a/YZltPZA  (2) slider - top nav bar appears BEHIND the slider   https://imgur.com/a/yWKwwba  (3) grid layout -  that jsfiddle isn't rendering the layout correctly, so you can't see it on that jsfiddle link, but when I hover over an item (in my local copy), the image appears ABOVE the top nav bar, like this: https://imgur.com/a/J4NmC1D   Many thanks in advance

Comment: Update: Actually, (3) is being demonstrated in the fiddle link.  https://imgur.com/a/rQrKRYo --> normal state  https://imgur.com/a/iWgflsU  --> once I hover over an item, the item appears ABOVE the top nav var